SQLExecDirect returns but stored procedure keeps executing
Currently I stumbled upon this issue. There is a SP which contains a lot of dynamic SQL code that is executed via exec(@stmt);
The SP takes around 45 minutes in SQL Server Management Studio and there it works fine.
If I call the SP in my C++ code with SQLExecDirect, the function returns with SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO (because of some warnings) and the SP keeps running in the background until the application closes the SQL connection.
Using MSODBC Driver 18 and SQL Server 2019
If I reduce the amount of dynamic statements, the SP is running fine. I could not pinpoint to a specific SQL query. All subsets run fine. It is the combination of all of them which do not work.
A query to SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT returns 0.
The application does not enable any ASYNC mode.
Has anybody seen this kind of behaviour before?
What can be the reason for this and how can I reliably execute my SP?

"Has anybody seen this kind of behaviour before?" If the answer was "yes", would that answer your question?

Does the stored procedure include anything that reports intermediate runtime information? e.g. SET SHOWPLAN ON, SET STATISTICS IO ON or SET STATISTICS TIME ON.

You should spool through resultsets and warnings etc or whatever one does in C++, it should probably then "catch up"

The SP uses 'set nocout on' to prevent affected row messages. No SHOWPLAN or STATISTICS

siggemannen had the right idea.
